# Large Network Layout algorithm without visualization

Tags: r, igraph, sna

Does anyone know of a resource where I can implement a force directed layout algorithm for a large network without visualizing it.  I tried R's igraph, but I couldn't figure out a way to get the x,y coordinates without the visualization.

Any tips would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DrL layout in igraph is quite good for larger graphs. I am not sure why you could not get the coordinates, it is rather simple:

```
library(igraph)
g <- ba.game(10000, 2)
system.time(coords <- layout.drl(g))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  93.629   0.726  96.424 
dim(coords)
# [1] 10000     2
```

Comment: Thanks! I think my being dense was the reason I couldn't get the coordinates.